# How do I set the homepage in ie from a DOS batch script

Tags: internet-explorer, batch-file

Is there a way to set the Internet Explorer homepage from a dos batch script.

I'm using:
Windows 2008 Server
IE 7

Comment: why do you need to do that through dos?

Comment: We have a bunch of dos batch scripts that install a web server. We need to verify the site is running by going to the web page so I might as well set the ie homepage to our site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the value for the home page is stored in the registry.

if all you want to do is set the home page, then a `.REG` *file* would be easier:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
"Start Page"="http://www.stackoverflow.com/"
```

if it's part of an installation, then you an use the `REG` command to access the registry:

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /V "Start Page" /D "http://www.stackoverflow.com/" /F
```